# Can't use the built-in wordpress install/upgrade plugin feature

Tags: plugins, updates, installation, permissions

When I try to upgrade or install a plugin I get a successful message:

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/jquery-lightbox-gallery.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Installing the plugin…

Successfully installed the plugin Fancy Gallery 1.0.27.

Activate Plugin | Return to Plugin Installer`
```

If however I have a look via ftp in my plugins directory the plugin has not been installed and the new plugin folder does not exist.

Then when I click the `Activate Plugin` link I get the following error `The plugin does not have a valid header.` which is not surprising considering the plugin hasn't been installed.

This happens no matter which plugin I try to install. It's strange because I have several other wordpress installations on the same host, and infact two other separate wordpress installations on the same domain and I have never had this problem.

I tried re-uploading a fresh installation of wordpress over the top of the current one and there was no change. I tried deactivating every single plugin and switching to the basic theme but it still didn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: So I tried making a new FTP account, and I can now add plugins using this new account. However when I try to upgrade a plugin I still get a `Could not remove the old plugin. Plugin update failed.` error.

Comment: It is a long shot, but try switching themes to rule out a theme problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried it, but that didn't help either.

Comment: So I tried making a new FTP account, and I can now add plugins using this new account. However when I try to upgrade a plugin I get a `Could not remove the old plugin. Plugin update failed.` error.

Comment: To anyone with the same problem - I don't know what caused it, but I got my host to switch me over to FastCGI (which eliminates the need for correct file permissions and ownership) and it now works.

Comment: @Nick5a1 Please add your solution as an answer and accept it